# Prove that $\cos{{\pi}\over3}=\sin{{\pi}\over{6}}=\frac {1}{2}$ with Euler's formulas

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So this should be pretty straightforward, but I keep getting stuck on a specific error.

My thought process thus far:

$$\cos{{\pi}\over3}=\sin{{\pi}\over{6}}=\frac {1}{2}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}(e^{i{{\pi}\over{3}}}+e^{-i{{\pi}\over{3}}})=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i{{\pi}\over{6}}}-e^{-i{{\pi}\over{6}}})=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\frac{1}{2}(e^{i{\pi}{{1}\over{3}}}+e^{-i{\pi}{{1}\over{3}}})=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i{\pi}{{1}\over{6}}}-e^{-i{\pi}{{1}\over{6}}})=\frac{1}{2}$$

$e^{-i{\pi}}=\cos(-\pi)+i\sin(-\pi)=-1+i*0=-1=e^{i{\pi}}$, therefore:

$$\frac{1}{2}((-1)^{{1}\over{3}}+(-1)^{{1}\over{3}})=\frac{1}{2i}((-1)^{{1}\over{6}}-(-1)^{{1}\over{6}})=\frac{1}{2}$$

But then $((-1)^{{1}\over{6}}-(-1)^{{1}\over{6}})=0$ and $0=\frac{1}{2}$, which is false.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. My guess would be the "$e^{-i{\pi}}=e^{i{\pi}}$" part, but that seems reasonable. Could you please give me a hint?

(On an unrelated note would also like to know if there is a name for this way of expressing $\sin$ and $\cos$. As far as I know it's not all Euler's work, so it's not really fair to call it Euler's expressions)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually, in a sense $(-1)^{1/3}-(-1)^{1/3}$ may not be $0$ (indeed for your case it shouldn't be). The idea is analogous to the following: If you know $x^2=y^2=4$, then  $x-y$ does not have to be $0$ because $x$ and $y$ may not be the same. 
In your case you care about different solutions to the equation $z^3=-1$.

Comment: Your first error: $\sin(\pi/6) = \frac{1}{2 i} \left(e^{i \pi/6} - e^{-i\pi/6}\right)$, not $ \frac{1}{2 i} \left(e^{i \pi/3} - e^{-i\pi/3}\right)$.

Comment: The "obvious" identity, $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$, which is true when $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all positive real numbers, is **not** true in general.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Yep, that's a typo, thanks

Comment: Why are you starting with what you are trying to prove.

Comment: $e^{-\pi i} = e^{\pi i}$.  But why would you think that means $e^{-k \pi i} = e^{k \pi i}$?

Comment: $e^{-\pi i*\frac 16} \ne (e^{-\pi i})^{\frac 16}$ any more than $-2=(-2)^1=(-2)^{\frac 22} =( (-2)^2)^{\frac 12}=4^{\frac 12} = 2$

Comment: @BarryCipra: Oh. Ok, I guess I'll keep that in mind in the future, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that 
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i\pi/6}-e^{-i\pi/6}\right)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-i \pi/2}\left(e^{i\pi/6}-e^{-i\pi/6}\right).\tag{1}$$
But
$$e^{i\pi/6}\cdot e^{-i\pi/2}= e^{-i\pi/3},\tag{2}$$
and 
$$e^{-i\pi/6}\cdot e^{-i\pi/2}= e^{-i2\pi/3}=e^{i\pi/3}\cdot e^{-i\pi}=-e^{i\pi/3}.\tag{3}$$
Therefore, $(1)$ becomes
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right) = \frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i\pi/6}-e^{-i\pi/6}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(e^{i\pi/3}+e^{-i\pi/3}\right).\tag{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are three cube roots of $-1$, namely $-1,e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}},e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}}$. Writing $e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}=(-1)^{\frac13}$ is not correct.